# Corrections for multiple hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni, false-discovery-rate

Apologies if this repeats a previous query, I have read a lot of prior threads (and made myself a bit cross-eyed with the ones asking whether we should correct for every hypothesis test ever performed!!) but haven't managed to clarify my particular query wrt to my current data analysis.

We've performed clinical measurements of tissue characteristics on a group of participants and are interested in comparing the differences when the participants are grouped by outcome (term vs preterm birth).

The measurements are spectroscopic, so multiple frequencies are used to take 14 different readings. We've hypothesis tested the individual frequencies to see what frequency range best discriminates the groups. The work is *fairly* exploratory (not the very first pilot, but the first substantive study) so there's not a clear precedent for what might be the optimal range, and I'm wary of being too stringent with p value corrections and obscuring true differences. In the pilot and at two separate timepoints in our study significant differences are evident at the same frequency range (which to me would seem to reduce the likelihood of these being Type 1 errors).
Study design pre-dated my involvement and a plan for corrections wasn't explicitly stated (I appreciate deciding post hoc is not ideal, so trying to select a rational option, rather than trying lots of different approaches.

I'm aware Bonferroni is esp conservative and indeed this removes any significance (this is the one I have tried as was most straightforward!). In some background reading ( https://www.bmj.com/content/310/6973/170 and elsewhere) it's been suggested that Bonferroni isn't ideal for correlated readings (which the spectroscopic data are, as they're measuring the same property at different frequencies), but I'm struggling to find a clear idea of what the best alternative might be. Currently considering a FDR approach with Benjamini-Hochberg procedure but would appreciate any thoughts on whether
a) I should definitely be performing a correction
b) If there's an ideal procedure to follow.

I also get confused about exactly how many ways to count the hypothesis tests - as I'm looking at two different timepoints should that count as 28 hypothesis tests (14 comparisons at different gestations) or correct each by 14. People seem to vary in the literature as to how they choose to apply it.

It also strikes me that if the single most predictive frequency had been used from the pilot I wouldn't be having this issue (but current spectroscopic instruments don't tend to use single frequencies for this application so in a way it constrains the experimental design.

Apologies if this is a rambling flight of ideas, any thoughts welcome!